# Wasabi In Sushi Go

Tags: sushi-go

In Sushi Go, what are the restrictions when playing Wasabi and Nigiri?

As I understand it;

- Wasabi is played
- Next Nigiri goes on top and has value tripled
- Nigiri does not have to be the next card

Is that right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is correct.

The wasabi and nigiri do not have to be consecutive cards, as long as there has been an unused wasabi played prior to the nigiri, they are (and must be) combined.

Answer (score 9):

Your assertion is right.  In order to use a wasabi, it must be played before the nigiri card.  Any number of other cards can be played in between.  Once you play a nigiri card, it uses one open wasabi card in front of you.

From the rules:

> #### Using Wasabi
>
> If you choose a squid, salmon or egg nigiri card,
> and already have a wasabi card in front of you,
> then this nigiri must be placed on top of the
> wasabi. This is to show that the nigiri has been
> dipped in wasabi and has tripled in value!
>
> NOTE: You may have multiple wasabi cards in
> front of you but only 1 nigiri card may be
> placed on each wasabi card.